# Want display page the same no matter the screen size bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I style the page that the display to be the same on the small screen and also on the large screen? On the large screen everything is perfect, but if I move the page on a smaller screen, then the things start to mess up. The following code: (it is made with bootstrap and css)

```
<div class="list-group">
            <ul class="panel-info col-lg-12 list">
                <li class="list-group-item list__item col-lg-4" ng-repeat="entity in entitiesPaginated">
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I will not write here all the code because I think the most important part is the bootstrap part, what should I change on it in order that the display to be the same no matter the screen display? Thank you

Comment: set col classes also for the other viewports: col-md-*,col-sm-*,col-xs-*

Comment: How to do that? I assumed the class col-lg-12 for example is from bootstrap. So where to edit this? In the default bootstrap file?

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, then first go through with the documentation, here we can't make you learn how to use bootstrap. First try to read the documentation how to use grid system of bootstrap, then you get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set col classes also for the other viewports: col-md-,col-sm-,col-xs-*

Here an example:

```
<div class="list-group">
            <ul class="panel-info col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 list">
                <li class="list-group-item list__item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="entity in entitiesPaginated">
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

You should read about the Bootstrap grid system

Comment: `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` is not necessary and is the same as `col-xs-12`. You should read about the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)

Answer (score 3):

Only use the grid class for the *smallest* breakpoint...

```
<div class="list-group">
            <ul class="panel-info col-12 list">
                <li class="list-group-item list__item col-4">
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

From the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)...

> For grids that are the **same from the smallest of devices to the largest**, use the .col and .col-* classes.

Note that in Bootstrap 4 Beta, the `-xs-` infix is no longer used since xs is the default breakpoint. It's simply `col-12` instead of `col-xs-12`.